# Как выбрать строку в таблице через SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, c++-cli

Здравствуйте. Пишу программу в Windows form c++/cli, опыта нет и только начал изучение.

Возникла проблема с выбором нужной строки.

Имеется такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как через SELECT вывести, минимальную стоимость для Заявки №1 или Заявки №2 в зависимости от того, что у меня указано в combobox1 (Название заявки).

Пробовал так:

```
MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase=gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from proba.zayavki where `Название заявки` = '"+this->comboBox2->Text+"' AND `Стоимость`=(SELECT MIN(`Стоимость`) FROM proba.zayavki)",conDataBase);
```

То есть получается он отбирает минимальное значение стоимости для всего столбца и выводит мне результат только если это верно для моей заявки.

Что можно сделать чтобы он выбирал минимальное значение для конкретной заявки?

Если что-то непонятно написал, то напишите.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение.

```
    SELECT article, dealer, price
    FROM   shop s1
    WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
                  FROM shop s2
                  WHERE s1.article = s2.article);

 article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
|    0003 | B      |  1.45 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0003 | D      |  1.25 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
```

Ответ был найден тут. [3.5.4. Строка, содержащая максимальное значение некоторого столбца](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/mysql-man-4.0-ru/tutorial.html#example-maximum-column-group-row) (MySQL.ru)

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(`Стоимость`)
from proba.zayavki
where `Название заявки` = :title
```

И задать `title`

Comment: спасибо за помощь! ниже выложил то что я хотел получить в итоге)